# What could possibly be causing these errors

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HasyG.jpg)

I am currently installing android studio and ran into some errors after the programs has finished installed.

This currently the code I am trying to run

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="me.marcusc.practiceandriod"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="20"
        android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

</manifest>
```

I have no idea what the results should be.

```
Error:(11) error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka me.marcusc.practiceandriod:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.

Error:(11) error: resource string/app_name (aka me.marcusc.practiceandriod:string/app_name) not found.

Error:(11) error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka me.marcusc.practiceandriod:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.

Error:(11) error: resource style/AppTheme (aka me.marcusc.practiceandriod:style/AppTheme) not found.

Error:(11) resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka me.marcusc.practiceandriod:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.

Error:(11) resource string/app_name (aka me.marcusc.practiceandriod:string/app_name) not found.

Error:(11) resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka me.marcusc.practiceandriod:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.

Error:(11) resource style/AppTheme (aka me.marcusc.practiceandriod:style/AppTheme) not found.

Error:failed processing manifest.

Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes Gradle experiences sync issues after running into a single error while compiling.

Try running these set of commands:

```
Build > Clean Project
Build > Rebuild Project
Run   > Run 'app'
```

If that doesn't work just `delete` the build folder within your project and run

```
Build > Make Project
```

Comment: Thanks .I am new to this so how would I go about running these commands.

Comment: build and run can be found at the top of the application's menu

Comment: Thanks alot. I was able to run the commands. It still seems to want to know the location the mipmap/ic_launcher. It  is still informing me that it cannot be found. Do you have an idea of what this might be?

Comment: Do you actually have the files in app/res/mipmap?

Comment: I simply download android studio. I thought i would come with all the necessary to operate. I do not know if I have to relocate the files to a different folder?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the error that I am having.

Comment: How would i be able to find these files or locate them?

Comment: try deleting that build folder in your files panel

Comment: You were right! I found the mismap folder then copied and pasted in the correct location. Fuey! Thx. But it seems like some of the files are missing still.

Comment: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka me.marcusc.practiceandriod:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.

Comment: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka me.marcusc.practiceandriod:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found.